Python-Scraper with BS4 and Selenium : Session-Issues with chrome
I am trying to grab the list of all the banks that are located here on this page
http://www.banken.de/inhalt/banken/finanzdienstleister-banken-nach-laendern-deutschland/1
note we've got 617 results
my approach: go and find those results - inc. Website with the use of Python and Beautifulsoup from selenium import webdriver.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# URL of the webpage
url = "http://www.banken.de/inhalt/banken/finanzdienstleister-banken-nach-laendern-deutschland/1"

# Start a Selenium WebDriver session (assuming Chrome here)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Change this to the appropriate WebDriver if using a different browser

# Load the webpage
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the page to load (adjust the waiting time as needed)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # Wait for 10 seconds for elements to appear

# Get the page source after waiting
html = driver.page_source

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Find the table containing the bank data
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "wikitable"})

# Initialize lists to store data
banks = []
headquarters = []

# Extract data from the table
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    cols = row.find_all("td")
    banks.append(cols[0].text.strip())
    headquarters.append(cols[1].text.strip())

# Create a DataFrame using pandas
bank_data = pd.DataFrame({"Bank": banks, "Headquarters": headquarters})

# Print the DataFrame
print(bank_data)

# Close the WebDriver session
driver.quit()

this gives back (in my colab)
SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-ccf3a634071d> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 
      8 # Start a Selenium WebDriver session (assuming Chrome here)
----> 9 driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Change this to the appropriate WebDriver if using a different browser
     10 
     11 # Load the webpage

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    227                 alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    228             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 229         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/124.0.6367.201/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5850d85e1e43 <unknown>
#1 0x5850d82d04e7 <unknown>
#2 0x5850d8304a66 <unknown>
#3 0x5850d83009c0 <unknown>
#4 0x5850d83497f0 <unknown>

Well I think that I have to take care - on Colab not every selenium will run flawlessly

You actually do not need selenium at all. The job can be achieved with requests and BeautifulSoup. First, you can get the max page from the pagination and construct the corresponding urls afterwards. Then you can iterate over the different pages and scrape the data in the table.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


def find_max_pages(url: str) -> int:

  r = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

  list_section = soup.find('div', class_='list')
  pagination = list_section.find('ul', class_='clearfix')
  last_pagination_item = pagination.find('li', class_="last").text.strip()

  return int(last_pagination_item)


def create_page_urls(last_page: int):

  url = "http://www.banken.de/inhalt/banken/finanzdienstleister-banken-nach-laendern-deutschland/"
  url_list = []

  for page_num in range(1, last_page+1):
    url_list.append(f"{url}{page_num}")

  return url_list

  
def scrape_bank_information(url_list):

  bank_list = []

  # Go over every page
  for url in url_list:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    list_section = soup.find('ul', class_='list')
    list_items = list_section.find_all('li')

    # Scrape every bank list item
    for item in list_items:
      
      bank_dict = {
          "bank_name": item.text,
          "headquarters_url": f"http://www.banken.de/{item.find('a')['href']}"
      }

      bank_list.append(bank_dict)

  
  bank_df = pd.DataFrame(bank_list)
  return bank_df
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  url = "http://www.banken.de/inhalt/banken/finanzdienstleister-banken-nach-laendern-deutschland/1"
  last_page = find_max_pages(url)
  page_links = create_page_urls(last_page)
  bank_df = scrape_bank_information(page_links)

I was not sure to what exactly you refer when you mention headquarters. If it means to scrape information on the separate sites, then you can again iterate over the scraped headquarters_url in the dataframe.

Simple get every bank page then get data one by one, in my exaple name and website. U can add some output for clarity, bcz the parsing process lasts several minutes, something like(past it in the last loop):
print(f'Get info from {bank_url}')

CODE:
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_urls() -> list:
    bank_urls = []
    response = requests.get('http://www.banken.de/inhalt/banken/finanzdienstleister-banken-nach-laendern-deutschland/1')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    last_page = int(soup.select('li[class="last"]')[0].get_text()) + 1
    for page in range(1, last_page):
        response = requests.get(f'http://www.banken.de/inhalt/banken/finanzdienstleister-banken-nach-laendern-deutschland/{page}')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        for x in soup.find('ul', class_='list').find_all('a'):
            bank_urls.append('http://www.banken.de/' + x.get('href'))
    return bank_urls


def get_info(url: str) -> dict:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    bank_name = soup.find('div', class_='single').findNext('h1').get_text()
    bank_web = soup.find('span', class_='companywebsite').get_text()
    return {'BANK NAME': bank_name, 'WEBSITE': bank_web}


result = []
for bank_url in get_urls():
    result.append(get_info(bank_url))
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)

OUTPUT:
                          BANK NAME                      WEBSITE
0                        1822direkt           www.1822direkt.de/
1    ABK - Allgemeine Beamten Kasse              www.abkbank.de/
2                  Aachener Bank eG     www.volksbank-aachen.de/
3             Allgäuer Volksbank eG  www.allgaeuer-volksbank.de/
4                      Allianz Bank  https://banking.allianz.de/
..                              ...                          ...
614                   fidor bank AG                www.fidor.de/
615                         netbank              www.netbank.de/
616                        noa bank              www.noabank.de/
617                  norisbank GmbH            www.norisbank.de/
618                     quirin bank           www.quirinbank.de/

